# Balão informativo em EditText - Android

Tags: android

Em sites existem vários campos informativos que ao clicar ou colocar uma informação errada meio que um balão surge dando uma devida informação, eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso em java para o android, se sim, qual lib ou componente eu uso? Como faço? Eu gostaria de fazer isto sem precisa inflar um layout, pois assim ele sobrepõe a tela. O efeito que desejo é algo similar a isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) em conjunto com um [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html). No seu XML ficaria:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="email"
        android:hint="Username" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

A sua classe TextWatcher ficaria:

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private TextInputLayout inputLayout;

        private MyTextWatcher(TextInputLayout inputLayout) {
            this.inputLayout=inputLayout;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            //Fazer a validação
            if (/* Condição para ser um texto inválido */) {
                inputLayout.setError("Erro. Esse email é inválido.");
            } else {
                inputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }
        }
}
```

E para aplicar o TextWatcher ao seu EditText, é só fazer:

```
txtEmail.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputLayoutEmail));
```

E o resultado será semelhante a este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]